# iOS - Google Maps Places onclick conflicts with map onclick

Tags: ios, google-maps, ionic2, ionic3

I have a project created with ionic. In here I have a Google Map with a places search box.

I have included the Google Map library like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=SOMEKEY&libraries=places" defer></script>
```

Now in my TypeScript code I have the following

```
// init the google map
initMap() {
    var centerOfMap;
    var draggableMarker = false;
    this.mapHasBeenInitialized = true;


    this.isStaticLocation = false;
    centerOfMap = new google.maps.LatLng(this.locationService.gpsLat, this.locationService.gpsLong);
    draggableMarker = true;

    var options = {
        center: centerOfMap,
        zoom: 11,
        fullscreenControl: false,
        disableDefaultUI: true, // dont allow default zoom/sattelite/street view
        gestureHandline: 'cooperative' // disable moving map with one finger
    };

    this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.googleMap.nativeElement, options);
    this.marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: centerOfMap,
        map: this.map,
        draggable: draggableMarker
    });

    if(!this.isStaticLocation) {
        var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(this.googleInput.nativeElement);
        // add the searchbar to the google map
        this.map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(this.googleInput.nativeElement);

        // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport
        this.map.addListener('bounds-changed', () => {
            searchBox.setBounds(this.map.getBounds());
        });

        searchBox.addListener('places_changed', () => {
            var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

            if(places.length == 0) {
                return;
            }

            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            places.forEach(place => {
                if(!place.geometry) {
                    console.log("returned place contains no geometry");
                    return;
                }
                this.setMarkerLocation(place);

                if(place.geometry.viewport) {
                    bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
                } else {
                    bounds.extends(place.geometry.location);
                }
            });            
            this.map.fitBounds(bounds);
        });
    }

    if(draggableMarker) {
        google.maps.event.addListener(this.marker, 'dragend', (event)=>{
            this.getMarkerLocation();
        });    
    }

    google.maps.event.addListener(this.map, 'click', (event: any)=> {
        var clickedLocation = event.latLng;
        this.marker.setPosition(clickedLocation);
        this.getMarkerLocation();
    });

    // neccessary for reload. Made async to trick loading process
    setTimeout(()=> {
        google.maps.event.trigger(this.googleMap.nativeElement, 'resize');
        this.map.setCenter(centerOfMap);
    }, 100);
}

// function to set the location marker on a different spot
setMarkerLocation(place: any) {
    this.marker.setMap(null);
    this.marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: place.geometry.location,
        map: this.map,
        draggable: true
    });
    this.getMarkerLocation();
}

getMarkerLocation() {
    var currLoc = this.marker.getPosition();
    this.locationService.setGoogleMapsLocation(currLoc.lat(), currLoc.lng());
    this.locationChanged = true;
}
```

And this code works like a charm in the browser and on Android. Basically what the code does is whenever someone taps on the map, the marker position changes to their tap location.

When a person searches for a Place, the places dropdown will show over the map. On android, when you tap a place in this dropdown, the marker will go to the selected place (f.e. australia).

On iOS however, the marker will position itself on the location where the person tapped and will totally ignore the tap on the place dropdown.

So when I'm in Europe and I type in 'Australia' and select 'Australia' from my dropdown, on Android I'll go to australia but on iOS I'll stay somewhere in Europe wherever the dropdown was positioned.